# New basement - want to seal concrete

Tags: cement, sealer

What would be the best product to seal a basement floor (brand new) that would not be slippery?  How long should I wait before applying product?

Comment: Normally most products specify 28-30 days (nominal cure time, during which you ideally keep the concrete damp/wet) - but check any product you choose for its specific recommendation on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Best product depends on your criteria for best.

Personally I use a flat (non glossy) concrete floor paint, water based so cleanup is easy. I'm not fond of gray concrete as a finished look, so unless the concrete was dyed some other color I don't want to see it - your mileage may vary, they do make clear concrete sealers if you like that look. Paint cuts dust generation, and improves lighting if you use a light color.

Some folks like to spend a lot more on epoxy coatings and then spend some more on making them not slippery.

Comment: They make a anti slip “sand” that you can mix with most coatings, after some research I found this to be 50 micron silicon carbide it looks like a powder and was quite expensive but after finding what it was I found it at a bead blasting web page for 1/4 what the paint store charged there are corse versions but I was concerned the larger grit would affect the seal so I never tried it but it is probably the same stuff just larger. I am one of the guys that like the 2 part epoxy because I haven’t seen it come up (that was in a garage not a house)